# Angular 4+ Video Frame Seeking Performance Optimization

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html5-video, hammer.js

I am currently implementing a UI inspired by this: https://dribbble.com/shots/2111528-Ice-Cream-Love-Motion

My current WIP can be tested here: https://datrinh.github.io/DesignHub17/

Important code snippets:

```
// Video Service
jumpFrames(direction: number) {
  const multi = direction > 0 ? AMOUNT_FRAMES_SKIPPED : -AMOUNT_FRAMES_SKIPPED;
  this.player.currentTime = this.player.currentTime + multi / FPS;
}

// Drag Component
onPanStart(e) {
  this.video.player.pause();
  this.startX = e.center.x;
  this.startY = e.center.y;
  this.startTime = this.video.currentTime;
}

onPan(e) {
  this.visible = true;
  this.x = this.startX + e.deltaX;
  // diameter offset
  this.y = this.startY + e.deltaY - DIAMETER;

  if (e.additionalEvent === 'panleft') {
    this.directionIcon = 'fast_rewind';
    this.video.jumpFrames(-1);
  } else if (e.additionalEvent === 'panright') {
    this.directionIcon = 'fast_forward';
    this.video.jumpFrames(1);
  } else {
    // TODO: How to handle 'panup' or 'pandown'
    // this.video.jumpFrames(e.deltaX);
  }
}
```

As you can see in the WIP app, the frame seeking isn't very smooth. There is a lot of stuttering. When moving too fast the functions don't get called the same amount of times like when moving slowly.

What can I do to improve the code? Is it even remotely possible to have the same smooth performance like seen in the animation?

Comment: For debugging, perhaps look into the buffered time/frames, using https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/av_prop_buffered.asp . If the frames you try to seek to are out of the buffer, maybe that's the trouble?

Comment: @cmonkey I am testing with a local video on my hard disk, too. That should remove the problem with buffering, shouldn't it? It doesn't seem to help much though.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the browser and how it handles/buffers the video. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652753/html5-video-with-seamless-loop-within-video having to do with the timeout for video handling.

Comment: @cmonkey maybe you are right about that. That would be a bummer since I would need to switch to a native implementation?